# can I connect an Iphone 4s to up 3 devices (temperature sensors) using BLE

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to know if I can connect my iphone 4s to three different devices. Those 3 devices are the same type devices. Those will be temperature sensors so, I have to receive the temperature from each of them. I have seent that it is possible to connect multiple devices to the iphone, but I am not sure that I can transfer normal data (temperature, GPS positions, etc. from multiple devices to Iphone 4s by using Bluetooth 4.0 (Low Energy).

Thanks for your help.

Javier

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm not aware of a hard limit for the number of LE peripherals that can be connected to a given LE-compatible iOS device. I couldn't find one in the documentation, at least, and Core Bluetooth supports multiple connected peripherals.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same on Corebluetooth ML, and an Apple Engineer said there is a limit to 10 in OsX (hardcoded in OS), but none in iOS (at most not hardcode).
Anyway, a shared rule of thumb is to consider that limit in iOS too.

Comment: Any body have accurate information for this? Especially for iOS device?

Comment: None at the moment, but next week I'll have our first 100 sample devices, so I'll try to verify how it works.

Comment: During last Apple Technology Forum, I asked  directly to Brian Tucker (Apple CoreBluetooth Senior Manager).
Brian was kind enough to give me an articulated answer:

there is no limit in concurrent connection, but problems rise during data transfer, because all connections share the same bandwidth, obviously.

Moreover, Bluetooth and Wifi share the same antenna, so the number of contemporary transferring devices are affected by the wireless activity.

Given these informations, a good rule of the thumb is to consider safe until about ten concurrent peripherals transferring data.